# Why is encryption so significant/difficult?

Tags: encryption

I'm a total beginner to encryption and I don't really understand anything about it.

Let's say I had a file TOPSECRET.BIN. What if I just:

- read file byte by byte
- XOR each byte by 69
- write "encrypted" data back into file

Sure it's simple, but how is anyone ever going to know how to decrypt that?

Comment: Should be on crypto.stackexchange.com -  And in short answer to your question, they would use cryptanalysis to analyse the data, and find patterns

Comment: Read " [The Gold Bug](http://etext.virginia.edu/etcbin/toccer-new2?id=PoeGold.sgm&images=images/modeng&data=/texts/english/modeng/parsed&tag=public&part=1&division=div1)" by Edgar Allen Poe.

Comment: Read this wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation and scroll down to the images comparing different block ciphers. Although, it is not exactly about XOR, you'll see how patterns in encrpyted text can leak information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *main* problem is that your ciphered text will still exhibit the hierarchical structure of the cleartext. So if the cleartext was english text, the same hierarchical structure you see in the english phrases will be in the ciphered message.

Answer (score 2):

If you XOR each byte with 69, figuring it out will be as simple as just trying 256 bytes to XOR. Plus language structure can be used for cryptanalysis.

You can use XOR for perfect encryption, though. Just choose a random sequence of bytes with length equal to your text and XOR it byte by byte. The random bytes will be your key. However, it will be as hard to communicate this key securely as it would be the message itself. And if you reuse this key, it would be easy enough to analyze multiple encrypted messages to figure it out.

Comment: What you mention in your second paragraph is called a [one-time pad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_time_pad)